# How to get product image dimensions in the listing page per product?

Tags: product-images

I have spent more than 3 hours to search how to get the exact dimension of product image(original) size in the listing page of each product, but everyone has answered that only resize width and height. But I need the image dimension to show under the title. How can i get that?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this code:
<?php
             $imageUrl =  $block->getUrl() .'pub/media/catalog/product'. $_product->getImage();
             list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageUrl); 
       $arr = array('height' => $height, 'width' => $width );
             print_r($arr);
            ?>

Comment: Thanks Abdul, but this isn't worked for me. Error showing `"Call to a member function getUrl() on a non-object"`

Comment: are using Magento1 & Magento2?

Comment: I am using Magento 1

Comment: Try this:

<?php
     if($_product->getSmallImage()) {
   $imageUrl=  Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product/'.$_product->getSmallImage();
         list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageUrl); $arr = array('height' => $height, 'width' => $width );
         print_r($arr); 
     }
    ?>

Comment: Pls check and let me know it is working or not

Comment: The code you have written below [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208025/how-to-get-product-image-dimensions-in-the-listing-page-per-product?noredirect=1#answer-208049) is working perfectly, but it is showing the small size, and I want the code to get original size.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
if($_product->getSmallImage()) {
    $imageUrl=  Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product/'.$_product->getSmallImage();
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageUrl);
    $arr = array('height' => $height, 'width' => $width);
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: This code is only showing the small sizes, but for actual size what shall i do?

Answer (score 1):

Check below code to get the orginial dimension

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth()
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalHeight()
```

Comment: Thank you Abhinav, but this code is providing all values same. I am getting the output as 262 x 262 in every product. But i have uploaded different sized product images.